# Sending sms with SmsManager with national language that has locking shift table

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I want to be able to send SMS in language that has national language locking shift table , Turkish for example .

**My goal is to be able to send SMS that includes 160 characters in one part in turkish language .**

I did searched a lot and what i found is that there is a class called GsmAlphabet that includes all the Locking Shift Tables specially for Turkish :

```
/* A.3.1 Turkish National Language Locking Shift Table
 01.....23.....4.....5.....6.....7.....8.....9.....A.B.....C.....D.E.....F.....0.....1 */
"@\u00a3$\u00a5\u20ac\u00e9\u00f9\u0131\u00f2\u00c7\n\u011e\u011f\r\u00c5\u00e5\u0394_" ...
```

Also i have function that can convert a String into a byte array containing
the 7-bit packed GSM Alphabet representation of the string.

**Can i achieve my goal with SmsManager and if yes, how ?**

Now days i am using to split each message with SmsManager "divideMessage" function and then send it with "sendMultipartTextMessage" function ,
I understand that i cant use this function for my goal because they support only strings as input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a clue about SmsManager, but you may follow these steps;

According to [National Language Shift Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#Turkish_language_.28Latin_script.29) specification, first you have to set UDHI to 0x40 indicate that your message has [User Data Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header) (UDH) in your message payload

place the UDH at the begining of message payload like: 0x03 0x25 0x01 0x01

```
0x03 -> UDH length (in this case 3 octet)
0x25 -> IEI indicates that header is National Language Locking Shift    
0x01 0x01 -> is for the Turkish Language
```

so your overall message will be like:
0x03 0x25 0x01 0x01 **rest of your message content..**